# Open url with parameters with cmd

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, command

I changed default program for `.docx` and set to `myopenwith.bat`

So when I clicked to any docx, it will **open with** `myopenwith.bat`

myopenwith.bat has this code:

```
start firefox https://www.dropbox.com/search/personal?file_categories=document^&path=/^&query=%~n0%~x0
```

Example, I have **test.docx** and try to **open with myopenwith.bat**

Firefox will open `https://www.dropbox.com/search/personal?file_categories=document&path=%2F&query=myopenwith.bat`

**But I need `https://www.dropbox.com/search/personal?file_categories=document&path=%2F&query=test.docx`**

How to fix this?
I need test.docx instead myopenwith.bat in url

Comment: Try `…^&query=%~nx1` [(parameter %0 is always the script itself)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). BTW, your Q is off-topic here, see at least [tour] and [help/on-topic].